# Cannot Import my Data from .CSV file into SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

Here is my specifications:

- My SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise 2019 (v15.0.2000.5)
- My Windows : Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2021
- My Office : Office 2016
- My CSV file full path: `F:\TaxStuff\StuffIDs.csv`

I have a big `StuffIDs.csv` file containing half a million records, I want to insert them into my SQL Server table.

This is a sample record from `StuffIDs.csv` file:

```
ID Type Date RunDate ExpirationDate SpecialOrGeneral TaxableOrFree Vat
 VatCustomPurposes DescriptionOfID
 
2710000173618 شناسه عمومی وارداتی(کالا) 1401-07-24 1400-10-13 عمومی
 مشمول 9 9 پودر شیر خشک صنعتی لبنیات فرآورده دامی

 2720000173617 شناسه عمومی تولید داخل(کالا) 1401-07-24 1400-10-13 عمومی
 مشمول 9 9 پودر شیر خشک صنعتی لبنیات فرآورده دامی
 
 2710000160892 شناسه عمومی وارداتی(کالا) 1401-07-24 1400-10-13 عمومی
 مشمول 9 9 کره حیوانی لبنیات فراورده دامی
 
2720000160891 شناسه عمومی تولید داخل(کالا) 1401-07-24 1400-10-13 عمومی
 مشمول 9 9 کره حیوانی لبنیات فراورده دامی
 
 2710000038252 شناسه عمومی وارداتی(کالا) 1401-07-24 1400-10-13 عمومی
 مشمول 9 9 کشک طعم دار لبنیات فرآورده دامی
```

**REMEMBER** my first row in that file is header and is:

```
ID  Type  Date  RunDate  ExpirationDate  SpecialOrGeneral TaxableOrFree  Vat  VatCustomPurposes  DescriptionOfID
```

What have I tried :

```
CREATE TABLE StuffIDs 
(
    ID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Type NVARCHAR(100),
    Date DATE,
    RunDate DATE,
    ExpirationDate DATE,
    SpecialOrGeneral NVARCHAR(50),
    TaxableOrFree NVARCHAR(50),
    Vat INT,
    VatCustomPurposes INT,
    DescriptionOfID NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

BULK INSERT StuffIDs
FROM 'F:\TaxStuff\StuffIDs.csv'
WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2, -- Skip the header row
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

The errors I got :

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 3 (Date).
>
> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 2 (Type).
>
> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 4, column 2 (Type).

Original file : https://ufile.io/ts1zfy3m

Comment: The DATE data in the source .csv file should be in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I would suggest to create a staging table where date columns will be as VARCHAR(...) data type.

Comment: I would also recommend staging your dates into `varchar(...)` columns. SQL Server's `date` data type expects values on the Gregorian calendar and you'll need to convert the Jalali calendar to the Gregorian calendar before you can store them in the `date` data type.

Comment: "FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', " - based on your `BULK INSERT` config your file uses comas as column delimiters. Where in your sample data can we find comas?